# Maximum entropy estimation for (only) one class in sklearn

Tags: machine-learning, scipy, statistics, nlp, scikit-learn

I want to use the library to estimate coefficients of maximum entropy model.

The setup of my experiment is as follows:

I have a set of annotated data: sentence plus a forest of its possible parse trees, of which only one is labeled as correct. I want to train a maximum entropy model to be able to score parse forests for unseen sentences. The problem is in the fact that the forests can be of an exponential size, so I would like to implement a custom algorithm to compute scores (product/sum of feature coefficients, computed dynamically) for making predictions. I would like to use only parse trees labeled as correct to compute the coefficients. My argument for skipping the incorrect data is that I do not need the probability, just the best score (and its derivation).

The problem is that sklearn expects the data to be annotated with at least two classes.

My proposed solution: 
Add 'artificial' feature which is activated only for one additional class and add one record to the training data that has only this one activated. It should not affect the results where this artificial feature will never be activated.

Does it make any sense to you? Can you advise any other solution? I would like to avoid implementing it from scratch.